# Solution to a linear system?

Tags: linear-algebra

Lets say I have a linear system of equations given by:
    $a_{11}x_1 + a_{12}x_2 + a_{13}x_3 = p_1$
    $a_{21}x_1 + a_{22}x_2 + a_{23}x_3 = p_1$
    $a_{31}x_1 + a_{32}x_2 + a_{33}x_3 = p_1$
You can assume that a unique solution exists for this problem. For the solution ($X_1, X_2, X_3$) to this problem the following happens:
    $b_{11}X_1 + b_{12}X_2 + b_{13}X_3 > p_1$
    $b_{21}X_1 + b_{22}X_2 + b_{23}X_3 > p_1$
    $b_{31}X_1 + b_{32}X_2 + b_{33}X_3 > p_1$
I need to find a solution such that the first set of equations are almost satisfied (in either direction ) i.e.
    $a_{11}x_1 + a_{12}x_2 + a_{13}x_3 \approx p_1$
    $a_{21}x_1 + a_{22}x_2 + a_{23}x_3 \approx p_1$
    $a_{31}x_1 + a_{32}x_2 + a_{33}x_3 \approx p_1$
and at the same time the following happens:
    $b_{11}X_1 + b_{12}X_2 + b_{13}X_3 < p_1$
    $b_{21}X_1 + b_{22}X_2 + b_{23}X_3 < p_1$
    $b_{31}X_1 + b_{32}X_2 + b_{33}X_3 < p_1$
What techniques can I use to solve such a problem? Furthermore, if a solution doesn't exist how can I check that out? How can I find a bound for the deviation of first set of equations from $p_1$.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility I see to solve this problem, is to formulate it as a convex optimization problem:

You want to achieve the following:

$\text{min}_x \lVert Ax - b\rVert^2_2$ such that $Bx \leq b$

Where $b\in \mathbb{R}^3$ and $b_i = p_1 \forall i$

Now, this optimization problem is convex and thus has a global optimum, if there is any. You can use CVX and Matlab for example to solve this problem, it is not a hard one to solve computationally.

Solving this problem, will give you the following insights:

1. If your optimum value of the minimization is zero, you know there is indeed a solution $x$, where $Ax=b$ and $Bx \leq b$.
2. If your optimum value is not zero, then it shows you, what is the best possible approximation $x$ in 2-norm sense, which satisfies $Bx\leq b$.
3. If the problem is infeasible, your condition $Bx\leq b$ does not hold for any $x$.

Comment: For my setup, using convex optimization seems like an overkill. Is there some other linear algebric approach that can help me solve the problem. I was trying to read upon perturbed linear system if I could use them for my setup. However, I am still reading and not sure if they will be useful in any way.

Comment: There's one more thing I would like to add to the problem description. All the b's are less than the corresponding a's. For example $a_{11}$ is less than $b_{11}$. Will that be useful in any way?